# Contador de caracteres en jQuery

Tags: jquery

He realizado un ejercicio con jQuery en el cual tengo que poner con color de fondo amarillo los párrafos que tengan menos de 100 caracteres, pero me pone cualquier párrafo en amarillo.

**Código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ejercicio 20</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
               if($('p').val().length < 100)
               {
                   $('p').css("background-color","yellow");
               }
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            p{display: table;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum cupiditate eaque explicabo ipsam magnam magni modi
            mollitia nobis optio placeat porro, quaerat quasi, quis quisquam quo similique sint sit tempora?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque
            eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque
            eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque
            eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer todos los elementos `p` y cambiar el fondo usando `this`, cuando la condición se cumpla.

Además, estás usando `val()`, para obtener el tamaño del texto. Debes usar `text()`, por lo que dice la [documentación de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The `.text()` method cannot be used on form `inputs` or `scripts`. To
>   set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the
>   `.val()` method. To get the value of a script element, use the
>   `.html()` method.

O sea, que `val()` se usa para recuperar valores en elementos de entrada y `text()` para valores que ya están en el DOM, como pueden ser `p, span,`...

También, he usado `function`, es preferible a `document.ready`, el cual es obsoleto desde jQuery3.

```js
$(function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text().length);
    if ($(this).text().length < 100) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>En amarillo</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum cupiditate eaque explicabo ipsam magnam magni modi mollitia nobis optio placeat porro, quaerat quasi, quis quisquam quo similique sint sit tempora? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a que no estas controlando individualmente el texto los elementos seleccionados sino el que el texto que contienen todos.

#### Solución:

- Usando [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) podemos controlar individualmente todos los elementos seleccionados
- Usando [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) podemos acceder al `texto` del elemento

#### Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('p').each(function(idx, element) {
    let $p = $(element);
    if ($p.text().length < 100) {
      $p.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum cupiditate eaque explicabo ipsam magnam magni modi mollitia nobis optio placeat porro, quaerat quasi, quis quisquam quo similique sint sit tempora? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos distinctio dolore doloremque eaque enim laudantium, nihil nulla obcaecati quod repudiandae soluta velit? Adipisci ipsum reprehenderit suscipit voluptas voluptatum?
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid dignissimos
</p>
```